# How to disable the button for sending friend request to itself?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my chat app like WhatsApp, I also added the friend req functionality, where users can be friend and unfriend with firebase database. Now the bug in my app is: I should not able to send friend request to myself, it must should Invisible the button but I don't know where should I hide. I'm bit confuse.

**Control flow of my app:**
Fresh app install - login/signup(StartActivity) - redirect to MainActivty - here I set menu layout and onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) - so there is All users option - from there I select any particular user(UsersActivity) - so it open user profile of that user(which is ProfileActivity) - there I'll get send friend req option.

But In all users activity, like other users, I'm also showing in list, and when I click it on my profile it shows same thing like other users and also shwoing "send friend request" option. How can hide that?

I'm attaching UsersActivity (where all users incukding me are showing) and ProfileActivity (where particular user profile will open and there I can get the send friend req option)

**UsersActivity.java**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference, UserDatabaseReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.usersToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Users");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(UsersActivity.this));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startListening();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue("true");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        }
    }

    public void startListening() {
        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child("Users")
                .limitToLast(50);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
                        .setQuery(query, Users.class)
                        .build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users users) {
                holder.setName(users.getName());
                holder.setStatus(users.getStatus());
                holder.setThumbImage(users.getThumbImage());

                final String userID = getRef(position).getKey();

                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("userID", userID);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, parent, false);

                return new UsersViewHolder(view);
            }
        };

        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }


    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            TextView userName = mView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            userName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            TextView userStatus = mView.findViewById(R.id.userStatus);
            userStatus.setText(status);
        }

        public void setThumbImage(String thumbImage) {
            CircleImageView circleImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
            Picasso.get().load(thumbImage).placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimage)
                    .into(circleImageView);
        }
    }
}
```

**ProfileActivity**

```
package com.jimmytrivedi.lapitchat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView profileDisplayName, currentStatus, totalFriends;
    private ImageView profileDisplayImage;
    private Button sendFriendRequest, declineFriendRequest;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference, FriendDatabaseReference, FriendDatabase,
            RootDatabaseReference, UserDatabaseReference;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String current_state;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        final String userKey = getIntent().getStringExtra("userID");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userKey);
        FriendDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friend Request");
        FriendDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends");
        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        RootDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        profileDisplayName = findViewById(R.id.profileDisplayName);
        currentStatus = findViewById(R.id.currentStatus);
        totalFriends = findViewById(R.id.totalFriends);
        profileDisplayImage = findViewById(R.id.profileDisplayImage);

        sendFriendRequest = findViewById(R.id.sendFriendRequest);

        declineFriendRequest = findViewById(R.id.declineFriendRequest);
        declineFriendRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        current_state = "not_friends";

        declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading user data");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we load the user data");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();


        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String displayName = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                String displayStatus = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();
                String displayImage = dataSnapshot.child("Image").getValue().toString();

                profileDisplayName.setText(displayName);
                currentStatus.setText(displayStatus);
                Picasso.get().load(displayImage).placeholder(R.drawable.defaultimage).into(profileDisplayImage);

                // ------------FRIENDS LIST / REQUEST FEATURE-------------

                FriendDatabaseReference.child(currentUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userKey)) {
                            String req_type = dataSnapshot.child(userKey).child("Request Type")
                                    .getValue().toString();
                            if (req_type.equals("receive")) {
                                current_state = "req_received";

                                sendFriendRequest.setText("Accept Friend Request");

                                declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(true);
                            } else if (req_type.equals("sent")) {
                                current_state = "req_sent";
                                sendFriendRequest.setText("Cancel Friend Request");
                                declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        } else {
                            FriendDatabase.child(currentUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(userKey)) {
                                        current_state = "friends";
                                        sendFriendRequest.setText("Unfriend this person");

                                        declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);
                                    }
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        sendFriendRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);

                // ------------NOT FRIENDS STATE-------------

                if (current_state.equals("not_friends")) {
                    DatabaseReference NewNotificationDatabase = RootDatabaseReference.child("Notifications").child(userKey).push();
                    String newNotificationId = NewNotificationDatabase.getKey();

                    HashMap<String, String> notificationData = new HashMap<>();
                    notificationData.put("from", currentUser.getUid());
                    notificationData.put("type", "request");

                    Map requestMap = new HashMap();
                    requestMap.put("Friend Request/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + userKey + "/" + "Request Type", "sent");
                    requestMap.put("Friend Request/" + userKey + "/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + "Request Type", "receive");
                    requestMap.put("Notifications/" + userKey + "/" + newNotificationId, notificationData);

                    RootDatabaseReference.updateChildren(requestMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if (databaseError != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "There was some error in sending request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                current_state = "req_sent";
                                sendFriendRequest.setText("Cancel Friend Request");
                            }
                            sendFriendRequest.setEnabled(true);

                        }
                    });

                }

                // ------------CANCEL REQUEST STATE-------------

                if (current_state.equals("req_sent")) {
                    FriendDatabaseReference.child(currentUser.getUid()).child(userKey).removeValue()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    FriendDatabaseReference.child(userKey).child(currentUser.getUid())
                                            .removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            sendFriendRequest.setEnabled(true);
                                            current_state = "not_friends";
                                            sendFriendRequest.setText("Send Friend Request");

                                            declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                            declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                }


                // ------------REQUEST RECEIVED STATE-------------

                if (current_state.equals("req_received")) {
                    final String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

                    Map friendsMap = new HashMap();
                    friendsMap.put("Friends/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + userKey + "/date", currentDate);
                    friendsMap.put("Friends/" + userKey + "/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/date", currentDate);


                    friendsMap.put("Friend Request/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + userKey, null);
                    friendsMap.put("Friend Request/" + userKey + "/" + currentUser.getUid(), null);


                    RootDatabaseReference.updateChildren(friendsMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


                            if (databaseError == null) {

                                sendFriendRequest.setEnabled(true);
                                current_state = "friends";
                                sendFriendRequest.setText("Unfriend this Person");

                                declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);

                            } else {

                                String error = databaseError.getMessage();

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

                // ------------UNFRIEND STATE-------------

                if (current_state.equals("friends")) {
                    Map unfriendMap = new HashMap();
                    unfriendMap.put("Friends/" + currentUser.getUid() + "/" + userKey, null);
                    unfriendMap.put("Friends/" + userKey + "/" + currentUser.getUid(), null);

                    RootDatabaseReference.updateChildren(unfriendMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {


                            if (databaseError == null) {
                                current_state = "not_friends";
                                sendFriendRequest.setText("Send Friend Request");

                                declineFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                declineFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);

                            } else {

                                String error = databaseError.getMessage();

                                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }

                            sendFriendRequest.setEnabled(true);

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue("true");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            UserDatabaseReference.child("Online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        }
    }
}
```

Please explain me with the code. I appreciate/upvote for your efforts and also waiting for your kind help. Thanks from Priyanka!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ProfileActivity`, just find out, if the user you are showing is the logged in user (compare user you get with `userKey` with your `currentUser`). If so, hide the `sendFriendRequest` like so:

```
sendFriendRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Alternatively, you could make the button disabled:

```
sendFriendRequest.setEnabled(false);
```